# Which is the best method to store an array in an android application without using SQLlite?

Tags: android

I'm working on a basic android app where in I have a list of items and each item consists of a list of around ten strings each.

1. How do I store the strings in an array for later use?
2. Can I use only one activity to display all the arrays?
3. When I display a single array(a page of text), how do I use a button and navigate to the next one in the list?

Thanks,

Sowmya.

Comment: you can use generic arraylist sowmya

Comment: what are your thought? what you have tried?

Comment: I was thinking of a string builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SharedPreferences of Android.

If you want to store a string array use [putStringSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)

A little example how to use the SharedPrefrences:
http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html

Comment: Haven't used preferences yet! Will give it a shot.! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the trick is to implement the interface Serializable. As long as the entire object graph you're trying to serialize contains only objects that also implement Serializable, the default serialization algorithm can use reflection to generate the byte stream for you, and you can output it to anything that can accept a byte stream

This is just one way to do it. You can do this by custom bean class and implement `Serializable` to that so now when you create `ArrayList<E`> of that class it is `Serializable`.

Example:

```
Class dataBean implements Serializable
{
    public String name;
}

ArrayList<dataBean> dataBeanArrayList = new ArrayList();
```

So `dataBeanArrayList` is now `Serializable` and you can also pass this between `Intent`.